# Does PouchDB have a http interceptor for fetching documents

Tags: angularjs, promise, pouchdb

In my Angular project fetch PouchDB documents in different places. And i would like to handle 401 Errors for all the `db.get()` functions. Is there a way to handle http errors without a catch?

```
db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
  // handle doc
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: why do you want to do something like this? Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar situation.

You can solve it in two ways, depending if you're using **live replication** or not.

**Without replication:**

1. You must attach a `catch(err)` handler to the `db.get()`
2. To make it less of a pain, create an Angular service to handle all of your DB calls, i.e. `PouchDbService`, and inject that into your Angular Component(s) constructor
3. Your `PouchDbService` should contain something like

```
    db;  // new PouchDB() reference

    dbGet(id, opts) {
      opts = opts || {};
      return db.get(id, opts)
        .catch(err, checkIfAuthError)
    }

    checkIfAuthError(err) {
      if (err && err.error) {
        if (err.status && (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403)) {
          return navigateToLogin();  // your logout logic, i.e. simple router, or logout service
        } else {
          throw(err);
        }
      } else {
        return Promise.resolve(false)
      }
    }
```

4. Then in your Angular Component(s), inject the `PouchDbService` and call the `dbGet()` method with your own `.then()` logic. *Note: in my implementation **non** 401/403 exceptions will still be thrown, so you may still want to handle them.*

```
    pouchService.dbGet('mydoc')
      .then(function (result) {
        // only reach here if auth succeeded
        // if 401/403, service would have already executed logout logic
      });
```

**With live replication:** (easier)

1. Add an error handler to your replication reference

```
    replicationRef = db.replicate.from('http://remote', opts);

    replicationRef.on('error', checkIfAuthError)
```

Answer (score 2):

No. You need to handle it in your exception part, since 401 is considered as an [exception](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/exceptions.html). 
It is always good to handle exceptions in exception logic, and separate exception logic from your code. Let's say your code is like this:

```
db.get('mydoc').then(function (doc) {
  //regular code
}).catch(function (err) {
  //Exception logic
});
```

If you try to handle an exception out of the exception part, it means that you want to bring an error into the regular code which does not make sense, and it's even dangerous.

Comment: Isn't it better to handle the error inside the first `then` ? You are not guaranteed to receive a Pouch emitted error in the second catch as the "regular code" can also raise an error.

Comment: Sorry. i don't get ur point? can u edit ur comment and explain more? what is `Pouch`?  and i don't get u at all about  in the sentence ` handle the error inside the first then ? `

Comment: Pouch is `PouchDB` . What I mean is that handling errors in `db.get().then(process, handle)` vs `db.get().then(process).catch(handle) ` are not equivalent. In your opinion is there a reason to use one rather than the other ?

Comment: @Salman When I get a 401 exception from Pouch.get() function I would like to reroute user to my login page so that the user can log in and become authorized. The reason why I ask is because i have a big project where I use pouchDB's get() function in different files and would not like to handle all of these separately. Each 401 exception should do the same thing, which is redirecting the user to login page.

Comment: Hoenstly, i am not familiar with `PouchDB` but, i can guess inboth cases `handle` method is responsible to perform a certain act in case an exception happen during the `process` operation. If it is the case, then they are equivalent, but have different syntax  for the same operation. And, regarding the question, here also they separate the exception code from regular code @adz5A

Comment: @HatoBrr I understand what you want. When you receive an exception, you cannot control the next command to run, and you will automatically be moved to the catch part. In your case, i suggest you to make the catch inside a parent function, and then call the function in all your project.